# django rest-farmework nested relationships to pass parameters

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization, django-serializer

Using django rest-farmework to implement the API,There is a problem has been unable to solve: How to pass parameters through the view.py to serializers.py? the specific code is as follows:

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    amount = models.IntegerField()

class Source(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rss_link = models.URLField()
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    # ForeignKey
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

views.py

```
class CategoryListView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        # How should this variable be passed to serializers.py?
        num_parameter = request.GET.get("num")

        category = Category.objects.all()
        serializers = CategorySerializers(category, many=True)
        return Response(serializers.data)
```

serializers.py

```
class SourceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Source
        fields = ("id","name","amount")

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    source_set = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_sources')

    def get_sources(self, category):
        sources = category.source_set.filter(amount=0)
        # I expect the code as follows,the "num_parameter" from views.py
        # sources = category.source_set.filter(amount=num_parameter)

        return SourceSerializer(instance=sources, many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ("id", "name", "amount", "source_set")
```

Program running results：

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "study",
        "amount": "0",
        "source": [
            {
                "id": 34,
                "name": "java",
                "amount": "0"
            },
            {
                "id": 35,
                "name": "python",
                "amount": "0"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

As annotated, modified the following code：

```
sources = category.source_set.filter(amount=0)
```

to

```
sources = category.source_set.filter(amount=num_parameter)
```

the "num_parameter" is from "CategoryListView", How to pass it to "CategorySerializer"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the serializer context:

```
def get_sources(self, category):
    num_parameter = self.context['request'].query_params['num']
    sources = category.source_set.filter(amount=num_parameter)
```

In your case, you need to pass the context when instantiating the serializer:

```
CategorySerializers(category, many=True, context={'request': request})
```

This is usually done automatically when using generic GenericAPIViews.

Comment: the result of ``self.context`` is ``{}``, so running ``self.context['request']`` is error " Exception Value: 'request' ".

Comment: The problem is solved by your help, thank you very much!@JoseKilo